# How to declare register values as an input in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have a data set consisting of 30 values and each of 16 bit wide. I tried to add these values as an input in my Verilog code in the following way:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module com (inp,clk,out);
input clk;
input reg [15:0] inp;//dataset
output out;
.
.
.
```

but when I am writing `input reg [15:0] inp;` it is showing `some error`.

Can anybody tell me how can I use this data set values as an input in my verilog code.

Comment: Registers simply cannot be inputs.  For a register you would have to decide the condition on which it adopts a value, and write a suitable assignment expression.

Comment: actually i am using inp=0 under always block, and got some error , can you suggest me instead of always block what can i use?

Comment: If you're assigning a value to it in this module, then it's not an input to this module. It's either an internal signal, an output, or an inout.

Comment: In my code i am using like , always @ (posedge clk); begin if(rst); begin inp=0,  means if(rst) input will be zero, and error is showing like procedural assignment to a non-register **inp** is not permitted

Comment: @TuhinDas - you simply cannot assign an input - that's fundamentally in contradiction with the very concept of an input.  Perhaps you want to make a registered *copy* of an input.  But that consists of having a register, and under some conditions assigning it the value of an input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign a value to *something*, then it is a register (`reg`). If you want to connect two things, then you need a `wire`. If you want to get a signal from an external block you use an `input` and if you want to send a signal to an external block you use an `output`. `output`s can be `wire`s or `reg`s, but an `input` cannot be a `reg`. If you're trying to assign a value to `inp` inside your block, then how can you also say the value of `inp` is determined by another block?

Maybe this is more what you're trying to do: on the clock edge, if reset is high then `inp_registered` gets `0`. Otherwise, it gets the value of `inp`:

```
module com(
    rst,
    clk,
    inp
);

input rst;
input clk;
input [15:0] inp;

reg [15:0] inp_registered;

[...]

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst == 1) begin
        inp_registered = 0;
    end
    else begin
        inp_registered = inp;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

Inputs are just inputs — there's no distinction between inputs driven by wires and inputs driven by regs.